# Encoding ™ £ for use in JSON - using objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, json, ios

In my iOS app I use JSON to pass data back and forth to a web service. I've been having issues when passing out characters such as £ and ™. Is there a built in function in Objective-c/Cocoa that can encode such characters for use in JSON?

Comment: Why are you not using a JSON library?

Comment: I am, I'm using this one http://stig.github.com/json-framework/

Comment: Does JSON framework not handle these?  It should; JSON requires support for UTF8 character encodings.  What makes you think it's not working?

Comment: I thought it would handle these characters but it doesn't seem to. I'm still waiting for a response from the developer on this issue. Just for the sake of it here's the error the JSON component gives me:

    {"id":null,"error":{"name":"JSONRPCError","message":"Unterminated string.","errors":[{"name":"JsonException","message":"Unterminated string."},{"name":"FormatException","message":"Unterminated string."}]}}

Comment: I'd try using NSJSONSerialization. "Encode characters for use in JSON" is nonsense - any JSON tool MUST be able to handle them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using the following to escape the data that I pass in my JSON calls. Worked for me so far.

```
NSString *_text = [text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Cheers Robert, I thought I'd tried this before but obviously not! It seems to work for me, I just wish I knew why the JSON component isn't doing for me, it seems like a pretty standard thing to me!